# Ruby on Rails, access to non persistent attribute and attribute default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to build application with survey functionality. To receive answers from users I've added non persistent attribute **is_checked** (also I have persistent attribute **is_right** in my schema).

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessor :is_checked

  def initialize
    self.is_checked = false
  end

  after_initialize :default_values

  private

  def default_values
    self.is_right ||= false
  end
end
```

But when I open rails console and run:

```
Survey.first.questions.last.answers.last.attributes
```

There is no **is_checked** attribute. If I call **is_checked getter** on answer instance I get **nil**.

Comment: I think the `initialize` method is started before you can access to this attribute. That means your `is_checked` attribute can't be `false` because it doesn't exist yet. You can put your line `self.is_checked = false` in a method that you start like this: `after_create :my_method`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imho your `initialize` method is never called, otherwise, since you do not call `super` you would loose all active-record initialization.

Your `initialize` definitely does not match the signature of the original (it accepts at least a hash), but the `after_initialize` was introduced exactly for this reason.

So I would just extend the `default_values` to include setting your `is_checked`.

Also `attr_accessor` creates access methods to an instance-variable, so just set that instance variable instead.

So I would write

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  attr_accessor :is_checked

  after_initialize :default_values

  private

  def default_values
    self.is_right ||= false
    @is_checked = false 
  end
end
```